# How do I calculate a score in a scikit-learn MLPClassifier. Getting numpy.float64 is not iterable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using a scikit-learn MLPClassifier (neural network) to classify some images.
The image data is returned as a multidimensional array of floats. If I don't convert the 1 hot-encoded labels to floats, I get a label mismatch when trying to train the model, so I convert them. However, when I go to score the predictions, now I get " 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable ". Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import pandas as pd
from skimage import io
from skimage import transform as trans
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier as NN
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Get the data
print ("Reading CSV...")
data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="hot_dog_data.csv", nrows=30)
X = data.values[1:,0]
Y = data.values[1:,1:8]

#convert the images to RGB number arrays
print ('Converting Images...')
img_converts = []
for line in X:
  img = io.imread("./images/"+line)
  img = trans.resize(img,(300,400), mode='constant')
  img_converts.append(img)
X = np.array(img_converts)

# Split into train and test vars
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.17)

# Reshape the image arrays into 2-D arrays so it will fit the model
xa, xb, xc, xd = trainX.shape
d2_trainX = trainX.reshape((xa, xb*xc*xd))

xe, xf, xg, xh = testX.shape
d2_testX = testX.reshape((xe, xf*xg*xh))

clf = NN(solver='lbfgs',hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)

# Recast the Y data so the fit won't get a label mismatch
trainY = np.asarray(trainY, dtype=np.float)
testY = np.asarray(testY, dtype=np.float)

print ('The machine is learning...')
clf.fit(d2_trainX, trainY)

print ('Predicting...')
count = 1 
for line in clf.predict(d2_testX):
  print (count, line )
  count += 1

print 'Calculating Accuracy...'
count = 1
for x,line in clf.score(d2_testX, testY):
  print (count, line)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: In the line `for x,line in clf.score(d2_testX, testY):` you're trying to iterate over a float value returned by `score()`. [See the documentation] (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.score).

Comment: Lol, it was the loop and not the score function. Wanna add your comment as a solution so I can mark it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
for x,line in clf.score(d2_testX, testY):
```

you're trying to iterate over a float value returned by `score()`.

> score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> ...
>
> Returns:  score : **float**

[See the documentation for score for more details.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.score)

Comment: Oh, it returns a float. That makes way more sense.